# question about getting started with the Here API

Tags: here-api

I am just getting started and thought I might see if anyone knew a good place to start...

I want to do a filtered list of Here Places in a mobile app.  Every time I think I've found the right path, like Here Places, it appears deprecated.

Where is the right place to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can check GS7 services in Here Here Maps.

Please find below details for your use-case scenario.

Services Overview
Discover provides users the ability to find a known place or address (partial or complete), as well as discover an unknown place. The latter requires information to help the end-user make a decision whether or not to visit. The expectation is that multiple items may be returned and the end-user will select the most appropriate.

Autosuggest provides term and query suggestions as the end-user types. Spell correction is included.

Geocode returns the geocoordinates for a single requested address. (NOTE: If the query is ambiguous, the API may return multiple items.)

Autocomplete provides completion of the entered keystrokes to the valid addresses. No spell correction is included.

Browse enables end-users to slice and dice HERE Map Content through various filters.

Lookup by ID finds one result based on its unique location ID.

Reverse Geocode returns the nearest address to known geo-coordinates.

Endpoint URLs
The following are the current endpoint URLs for submitting API requests:

autosuggest - https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest
search - https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover
geocode - https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode
autocomplete - https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete
browse - https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse
lookup by ID - https://lookup.search.hereapi.com/v1/lookup
revgeocode - https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode

Please check the following [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoints-overview.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with a mobile app, I would recommend the **HERE SDK for Flutter**. There is a good staring point to [search for HERE places](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/dev_guide/topics/search.html#search-for-places).

Even better, there is also a [free app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/search_app) with all the source code you need. It's open source, so you can use it for your own projects. Just try it out and see if it gives you what you need.

Searching for places is not requiring much code:

```
_searchEngine.searchByText(query, searchOptions, (SearchError? searchError, List<Place>? list) async {
  if (searchError != null) {
    return;
  }

  // If error is null, list is guaranteed to be not empty.
  for (Place searchResult in list) {
    ...
  }
});
```

This code is written in Dart, so you can compile and run it on iOS *and* Android devices.